# Convert UTC date seconds to Date

Tags: javascript, date

Pretty straightforward issue, but I haven't found any information on this after looking around a bunch.

Essentially, I want to convert a series of UTC dates (e.g. "1505952000") into regular date strings (e.g., "9/21"), to use today as an example.

For some reason, however, `.toDateString()` is erroring out as "not a function" when I try to run it. How do I make this simple conversion work?

Here's my code, and I've console-logged day.dt to ensure that it's a valid UTC date when it runs:

```
let dt = day.dt.toDateString();
```

Comment: Did you try just `new Date(1505952000 * 1000)` and then format the date any way you want ?

Comment: `day.dt` likely isn't a `Date` object.

Comment: Woah. 1) that was fast 2) that worked 3) why does multiplying that number by 1000 and passing it into a Date constructor convert it? Thanks for your help

Comment: A number is just a number. You have to create the Date object to be able to access methods on it

Comment: 1) That's what my girlfriends says as well ... 2) sure did ... 3) because you had seconds, and javascript accepts milliseconds.

Comment: That's a wrap, gentlemen. Love this community :)

Answer (score 1):

UTC var stored *in seconds* from Jan. 1, 1970.

So to convert it back to the local date time, use this snippet:

```js
var d = new Date(0);
d.setUTCSeconds(1505952000);

console.log(d);
```

OR

```js
var d = new Date(1505952000 * 1000); // Because this constructor takes miliseconds.

console.log(d);
```